# PostgreSQL: Group value every n rows

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a simple table with date and budget values

| budget | date |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2022-05-01 |
| 5 | 2022-05-02 |
| 15 | 2022-05-03 |
| 16 | 2022-05-04 |
| 22 | 2022-05-05 |
| 13 | 2022-05-06 |
| 23 | 2022-05-07 |
| 56 | 2022-05-08 |

I want to group **every N rows** in one with PostgreSQL statement.
I expect to see something like this, if **N = 2** (for example, it also can be 3 or 5, it depends)

| budget | date |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 2022-05-01 - 2022-05-02 |
| 31 | 2022-05-03 - 2022-05-04 |
| 35 | 2022-05-05 - 2022-05-06 |
| 79 | 2022-05-07 - 2022-05-08 |

If it more that 2, the date should be formatted as **start_row_date - end_row_date** (2022-05-01 - 2022-05-03 for N = 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with some math which to represent `N` if your `"date"` might be datatype we can try to use `TO_CHAR` to get the format as your expected.

```
SELECT SUM(budget) budget,
       CONCAT(MIN("date"),'-',MAX("date")) date
FROM (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "date") rn
  FROM T 
) t1
GROUP BY (rn - 1)/2
ORDER BY (rn - 1)/2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0a5f1c1d40e88810fbf7948f19882b5d)

Comment: Thanks for fast and good working answer !

Comment: @D-Shih i feel that your last modified query only works for 2 dates. It is not dynamic right. But it is fully optimized. Your brilliant .

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution provided by @D-Shih. He is the owner of the logic and i convert it into a DB function for easy access for other viewers

> Note: T = budget_table , Date = bud_date

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION budget_function(num integer)
RETURNS TABLE(budget bigint, dub_date text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin

    return query
        SELECT SUM(t1.budget) budget,
               string_agg(TO_CHAR("bud_date",'YYYY-MM-DD'),'-') date
        FROM (
          SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "bud_date") rn
          FROM budget_table
        ) t1
        GROUP BY (rn - 1)/num
        ORDER BY (rn - 1)/num;
    
end
$function$
;
```

Try

```
select * from budget_function(2);
select * from budget_function(3);
```